# How to fix SSH broken from just one machine?

Tags: windows-10, ssh, freebsd

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I was connected just fine, changed my password, logged out, then attempted to reconnect again, and got the above error.  My client is Windows 10 with both Cygwin SSH as well as PuTTy.  Server is FreeBSD.  Notably, if I SSH into a different server (also FreeBSD), THEN into the troublesome one, I can get in.  However, I can't SSH directly to the first one anymore.

I've tried:

- Deleting my local SSH data
- Using different SSH clients locally
- Checked for stuck sessions and connections on the server
- Done verbose output locally and it's all normal until it suddenly is closed remotely
- Checked the remote server hosts.allow and hosts.deny (as well as firewall)

What else could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denyhosts decided to block me.  Reason unknown, but when I was removed from denyhosts I could login again from that machine.